# Can it be proved that any interval is larger than another interval?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is a problem phrased as the best mathematics analog I could think of for a contradiction that per my intuition, presents itself in physics.

In an infinitely continuous set of values such as the number line, is it possible to prove that any given interval is larger than a different interval without reliance on an indivisible unit that can be used to perform measurements against?

The apparent contradiction here is, what will indicate the size of an interval if every interval seemingly contains an infinite number of infinitely smaller intervals?

Comment: I think it means the lebesgue measure

Comment: Sounds like you are investigating the beginnings of measure theory (or maybe lattices, where order can be theorised without reference to absolute size)

Comment: You might find [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/685650/81360) interesting. There is a notion of "how big" a set of numbers is (known as "Lebesgue measure") and a notation of "how many" elements a set contains (known as "cardinality). The way that these two notions interact is not always intuitive.